# Positioning elements using z-index is causing unexpected result

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to implement a popup menu in html using z-index. The page is composed of a top bar an a tab bar below it.
I want to apply box-shadow to both of them, so I can't use position:static. 
The tabs-bar should have a z-index larger than the nav-bar's so it hides the box-shadow of the nav-bar (so when I hide the tabs-bar I would like to see the box-shadow of the nav bar)

The drop down menu should be place on top of both, but for some strange reason, it is placed on top of the nav-bar, but behind the tab-bar, although its z-index is set to a value higher than both.

I read about z-index contexts, but I can't seem to understand what is going on here. 
here is a link to codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvgMXX

**HTML:**

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      Nav bar
      <div class="menu"> drop down menu</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs"> tabs bar </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: gold;
  position: static;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 11px -5px #000;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.tabs {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 11px -5px #000;
  z-index: 101;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: gold;
  top: 30px;
}

.menu {
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try change `z-index` in `.tabs` and `.menu` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown menu is contained in `.navbar`. A `z-index` value of child wouldn't affect if the parent's `z-index` is smaller to item in comparison. You need to increase `.navbar` z-index.

See the updated pen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLGXvP

On a side note, there's huge z-index abuse, you can step with multiples of 3s or 9s. using 100 and 2000 is incredible waste. Same goes with unnecessary positioning.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about value abuse. I took a note to myself.
As for the z-index problem itself, the tabs-bar is not the parent of Nav-bar, they are on the same level..

Comment: No, but navbar is parent to dropdown menu. And navbar has z-index of 100 which is less than 101 if tabbar. Hence your menu is coming below

Comment: Check the codepen I've mentioned, it has right solution

Answer (score 0):

Since your dropdown menu is placed inside the nav bar, you can set it's `z-index` as high as you want, but it will never be higher than the one of it's parent. You could put it outside the nav bar: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wvgzrg

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the tabs-bar is not a parent of nav-bar. I'm trying to understand the behavior of z-index in this case

Comment: But the nav-bar is parent of the dropdown. The nav-bar has a lower z-index than the tab-bar, so the dropdown is placed behind the tab-bar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but if you remove the "position: relative" property from your navbar, it works fine. I tried it in Chrome.

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 11px -5px #000;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/11wkyvat/